# Re-raise bluffing post flop in heads-up cash game

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-strategy, betting-strategy, poker-tools

I am struggling with Post Flop bluff raising, to a bet, playing heads-up cash game.

I am unable to decide, other than big drawing hands, when to bluff raise after flop. How should I make a strategy for this?

If there is any reading or video material then please provide link. I will appreciate your advice.

Comment: Can I ask, this will help with answering the question, but how comfortable are you in your game, how experienced are you and how comfortable are you in the stakes you're playing? These things can matter as if you're completely uncomfortable bluffing will probably not be the wisest thing, if you are comfortable we can expand the range, etc.

Comment: Also what stakes are you playing? This too will help answer this question.